# How do I get Hpricot 0.6 Gem Built on FreeBSD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, freebsd, hpricot

When I run rake gems:build with hpricot 0.6.164 on my FreeBSD server I get:

> Error: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /user/localbin/ruby18 extconf.rb gems:build RB_USER_INSTALL
>   checking for main() in -lc... yes
>   creating Makefile
>
> make
>
> make install
>   /usr/bin/install -c -o root -g wheel -m 0755 hpricot_scan.so /user_directory/vendor/gems/hpricot-0.6.164/lib/universal-java1.6
>   install: /user_directory/vendor/gems/hpricot-0.6.164/lib/universal-java1.6/hpricot_scan.so: chown/chgrp: Operation not permitted
>   *** Error code 71
>
> Stop in /user_directory/vendor/gems/hpricot-0.6.164/ext/hpricot_scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to set RB_USER_INSTALL to true when running the rake gems:build command.

Example:

> RB_USER_INSTALL=true rake gems:build